# Finding point within box using MongoDB?

Tags: coordinates, mongodb, within

Suppose the point has coordinates for a search within the box: 
**(long:-155, lat:19)**

If we have the box: **SW - (-170, 10), NE (29,69)** that everything is fine and we can find this point because it's inside this box.

But if we move the box a little bit the coordinates are **SW - (144, 10), NE** **(-75,69)**   that results are zero although the point is still inside of this box.

How to do it properly to find the point in the second situation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `geoIntersect` , not `geoWithin`

if you are using java to work with mongodb: view the answer: [mongo geoIntersects with Spring Data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275018/mongo-geointersects-with-spring-data)