# mongo geoIntersects with Spring Data

Tags: geojson, intersection, mongodb

I created a collection that contains a multipolygon document.

I want to write a query in spring data that tells me if a point (lon, lat) intersects the multipolygon.
The query in mongoDb is as follows:

```
db.my_multi_polygon.find({
    geometries : {
        $geoIntersects : {
            $geometry : { 
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 12.704157, 41.720075 ] 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but I would like to understand how to translate it into Spring Data

Is it possible to write a query that returns a boolean (true = intersects, false = not intersects)?

Answer (score 1):

Was stuck on this too for a bit, this is my solution:

Example domain model:

```
public class Foo{

   @GeoSpatialIndexed(type=GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
   GeoJsonMultiPolygon polygons;

    public GeoJsonMultiPolygon   getPolygons()
   ...
}
```

your FooDAO:

```
public List<Foo> findByPolygonsIntersects(GeoJsonPoint point){
    DBObject geoJsonDbo = new BasicDBObject();
    mongoOperations.getConverter().write( point, geoJsonDbo);
    BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery( new BasicDBObject("polygons" new   BasicDBObject("$geoIntersects", new BasicDBObject("$geometry",geoJsonDbo))));
return mongoOperations.find(basicQuery,Foo.class);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution could be here

```
    GeoJsonPoint point = new GeoJsonPoint(new Point(lat,lng));
    Query query = new Query().addCriteria(Criteria.where("polygons").intersects(point));
    List<Foo> list = mongoTemplate.find(query, Foo.class);
```